# How to plugin custom converter in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, nosql

I am using Couchbase 4.1 and java sdk 2.2. I am trying to put java object in couchbase using **EntityDocument**. Below is code snippet

```
    EntityDocument<PAdminLog> jsonObject = EntityDocument.create(pAdminLog);
    bucket.repository().insert(jsonObject);
```

I am getting following exception when I run my application

```
2016-01-21 18:08:56,957 8664 [main] ERROR c.p.m.PAdminLogGenerator - com.couchbase.client.java.repository.mapping.RepositoryMappingException: Unsupported field type: class java.util.Date
    at com.couchbase.client.java.repository.mapping.DefaultEntityConverter.fromEntity(DefaultEntityConverter.java:71)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.repository.mapping.DefaultEntityConverter.fromEntity(DefaultEntityConverter.java:31)
```

So from exception its clear that **DefaultEnityConverter** in java SDK 2.2 is not capable to convert java date.

Is there any why to plug-in custom converter so that I can convert java data while persisting and retrieving data from Couchbase ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Repository` feature is still experimental (as in very simple), so there's no way of plugging-in custom converters.

It suffers the same limitations as the `JsonObject` (which is also intended as a small, simplistic API bundled with the SDK as a no-dependency alternative to bigger fishes like Jackson, GSon or Spring). We are thinking more and more about introducing custom converters to `JsonObject`, which would benefit `Repository` as well.